# Kitten refuses to eat after mama cat's death. Getting weaker

Tags: cats, domestication

[Cat throws up for a while. Leaves forever](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/33175/cat-throws-up-for-a-while-leaves-forever)

The kitten in question is of the mama cat about whom i have written in the above question.
She refuses to eat. Drinks water but goes on to sit in water or cold places. She is getting weaker. Its 18 hours since she has eaten anything. Nearby vets aren't available too due to public holiday. Kindly advise. Its 10 weeks old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sitting in water = it is feeling too hot. Most likely it has a fever. This fever could be due to an unrelated illness, or stress over the mother's death, or the same infection/poisoning that took the mother and transmitted through saliva or milk. Hopefully it is not serious.

As a first step, try measuring the internal body temperature. Search YouTube if you don't know how (the anus is the easiest and most reliable).

Second, use a syringe and feed it with oral rehydration solutions. It is a mix of glucose/dextrose and essential salts. Also try giving small amount of liquid kitten food or diluted cow milk with the syringe and check that it doesn't vomit it back out.

Third, try to consult an actual vet online via video. If they are nice enough and good at their job, you can get a preliminary diagnosis without a physical visit.

If there are no vets available try asking a vet medical store. Sometimes the store pharmacist can be very helpful in a pinch.

If the vet recommends an antibiotic injection, maybe you or someone nearby can administer it intramuscularly without waiting for the hospital to open. Get the ratio and quantity right if you choose to administer the injection yourself.

Act fast. Kittens can die quickly.

Comment: Thanks much for taking out your time and giving valuable tips. I was measuring the temperature and it was dripping every hour.I fed her with ORS solution and proviboost drops in hope of it feeling hungry and back to eating. She didnt want to be disturbed, no matter how much i pull her in she would just return back and sit at the place where its mother would sit. In an hour she had a huge hiccup where she spilt out the solution. Another few hiccups and my friend of few weeks just entered the other world. I feel regretful that I couldn't save it. Probably it was too attached to its mum.

Comment: Terribly sorry for the loss. It is painful to lose both cat and kitten one after the other. Yes it is possible it missed the mother too much and its body couldn't handle the stress. How kittens are left? If there are any still around, pay close attention to them, what they are eating and pooping, if they are vomiting. Infection/virus can often spread through saliva/milk from mother to kitten. If a second kitten falls ill you should be almost sure of an infection and consider a basic antibiotic course immediately. And get the kittens spayed/neutered soon so the urge to "roam" is controlled.

Comment: It's likely she was either sick, or impacted by whatever poison afflicted her mother; I would recommend taking the remaining kittens into the vet *as soon as possible* regardless of whether or not they are symptomatic, and explaining what's happened to this one. If they are also impacted, early intervention is your best bet to save them.

Comment: Actually, in addition to monitoring the eating/pooping/vomiting, try to monitor the temperature of the remaining kittens. Cats are notoriously good at hiding illness initially and then suddenly worsening and dying. Without the mother around, their feral/wild instincts can kick in. So take good care of them and be gentle.

Comment: 2 more kittens are present from that litter. They are doing good as of now but will definitely take them to vet tomorrow just to rule out any poisoning or infection. @yogesch and alison thank you so much for being around with your support. Its been terrible week so far for me. Will keep posted after vets visit

Comment: The thought keeps running in my mind whether I should've force fed her with all ors n other things yesterday itself when she became silent and stopped eating. Feels like me being responsible for her death. Can't control the emotions pouring.

Comment: Yes, it is natural to feel that way. Even if you had, at such a young age, the aftercare could have been a nightmare. If it couldn't last a less than a day on its own, either 1) its condition was already bad, or 2) the illness was severe. So no, your action would have felt better but the likelihood of it having made a real difference is not too high.

Comment: Never feed cows milk! This is terrible especially if the cat is weak already. Cats in general can not digest lactose.

Comment: @Allerleirauh Adult cats have lost lactose tolerance. Kittens still drink mothers milk, so why would a kitten be lactose intolerant..

Comment: @Yogesch please have a look into [this](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/28892/feeding-25-day-old-kittens-with-buffalos-milk-in-addition-to-mothers-milk/28893#28893) question and search for "kitten cow milk" in pets.SE, nearly all experinced persons seem to agree that cows milk also for kittens it not good :(

Answer (score 2):

I used to work for a feline veterinarian. First you have to get some food in her. Most cats can't refuse baby food of the strained meat varieties. ( all meat ) I would feed them with a syringe and as they improve you can try putting it on the side of their jaws. They will clean it off and in the process eat the food.

Comment: I am currently feeding the mashed ocean fish canned food in syringe. How often should I feed and how much quantity pls advise. Also it has worms, and its second dose of deworming is due next week, should i wait for it to recover or feed the dewormer again now.

Comment: @MueezSiraj You should feed the dewormer **exactly** like instructed by the package or your vet. It usually kills only the adult worms, but not the eggs of them. After all adults are killed by the first dose, you wait for all the eggs to hatch and then kill the new worms with the second dose. If you give the second dose too soon, some eggs survive and your cat will have worms again in a few days.

Comment: @Elmy okay then I'll wait before the next dose. Can you advise about feeding please. It comes out to eat but doesnt really pick it up, I tried all the different foods which it used to eat but he seems to be disinterested. I'm warming up with the heater and am able to feed just 1-2 ml of canned food an hour as after that it doesnt open mouth for a long time again. avoiding milk too due to diarrhoea fear. what else can i feed.

Comment: @MueezSiraj I don't know what else to do. I would continue feeding the same food and gently massaging the tummy after it finished eating. This helps with digestion and a mother cat would do the same by licking the kitten. But a 10 weeks old kitten should be able to digest without this massage, too. Keep in mind that the stomach of a tiny kitten is even tinier. Feeding just a little bit of food every few hours is better than forcing the kitten to eat more than it wants. Avoiding milk is the right thing to do.

Comment: It is having loose stools. I suspect because of new canned food but not sure. Should I feed it with curd or sporlac(anti diarrheal medicine for human). Or any other thing which is advisable?